# Alpha Particles Moving Object

Tags: mass, radiation, collision

I'd like to apologize in advance because this may be a silly/obvious question, but could alpha particles theoretically move an object?

My basic idea is that alpha particles could cause an object to move if enough particles are directed towards the object. Alpha particles have mass and quite often do not penetrate/pass through an object. So if the alpha particles collided with the side of an object, wouldn't the collision cause the object to be pushed away from the collision points of the particles? Of course the object must be dense enough to deflect/resist the particles - meaning the alpha particles must be incapable of completely passing through the object.

Is this idea correct and can anybody supply more information (or links to more information) about this subject?

Again, I apologize if the answer is obvious. I can't say I know too much about physics, but I figured this would be the best of all places to ask.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right, it is fairly obvious. Conservation of linear momentum applies at all times! If an object is irradiated by alpha particles, each with mass $\sim 4m_u$ and travelling with velocity $v$, and if it absorbs $N$ of these particles in a time $t$. Then the force exerted on the object is the rate of change of momentum.
$$ F = \frac{4Nm_u v}{t}$$

Of course it will be a bit more complicated than this. Many of the alpha particles will be deflected (or even reflected), rather than absorbed in the material, so the calculation of the change of momentum (the numerator in the equation above) will need modification. That would require knowledge of the distribution of the velocities, as a function of angle, of the alpha particles as they exit the target, as well as the fraction that are absorbed.

Comment: Thank you, I figured this must be the case, but given my lack of knowledge in the field of Physics, I decided I wanted someone with more expertise to validate it. If it's not too far out of the scope of this question, would the same be true for a light wave. I have read that a light wave has mass proportional to `E = mc^2`, so would the photons of light waves be able to cause the same effect due to the conservation of linear momentum?

Comment: Photons have momentum $E/c$. If dealing with light classically, it exerts a force given by $c^{-1}$ times the Poynting vector integrated over the absorbing surface.